# NoSuchMethod with addAll in Adapter?

Tags: java, android

I have a subclass of an ArrayAdapter declared like this

```
public class ShoppingCartAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShoppingCart> {
```

and everything has been working fine. Now suddenly(?) I have problems with this on my Nexus S running 2.3.6 or an emulator with 2.2 throwing

```
12-19 14:33:36.136: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.somewhere.mobile.fragment.ShoppingCartListFragment$ShoppingCartAdapter.addAll
```

however it still works just fine on e.g. my Xoom with 3.2.

I am not overriding the super addAll methods and since it works on some device I am not sure where to look next. Any hints?

UPDATE:

I replaced adapter.addAll(newCarts) with

```
for (ShoppingCart cart : newCarts) {
  adapter.add(cart);
}
```

and that works. I assume it has something to do with generics but have been unable to nail it down yet.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
addAll(...)
```

has been added starting from API 11 (Android 3.0). Here the [doc.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29)

Comment: Doh... did not even check on that since I am using it for ArrayLists just fine in other places. Silly me. Thanks

Comment: No problem man! That method is so useful, it sucks that they just added only starting from Android 3.0!

Comment: then what is the solution for the older version of android?

Comment: You are extending ArrayAdapter so you don't have access to the list of items. As consequence you need to add items one by one. Different game if you are using a BaseAdapter. @Emmy

Comment: @gwa, yes, as soon as i posted the comment, I figured that out. :)  thanks for your reply.  I'd like to support older version of android so that the people have older devices can use my app.

Comment: Why does the compiler not detect this? I have app with min sdk 7 and this method. This could be detected by the compiler

Comment: @Ixx, seconded, thats what I was gonna ask also. Does anyone know why this isnt detected by the compiler?

Comment: Specifying "minSdkVersion" doesn't change the build target. If you change your *build target* to the "min" version you have in mind, the compiler then will detect stuff like that (if you run a newer build target it can't). See "Selecting a Platform Version and API Level" here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html.

Answer (score 12):

addAll(...) is not available in lower API levels. Its added in API 11 and above. So use add(...) to fix this issue as follows

```
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++) {
        adapter.add(contents.get(i));
    }
```

instead of

```
    //adapter.addAll(contents); //do not use addAll(...)
```

Comment: You might want to check the build version at runtime before you do that, ala "Check System Version at Runtime": http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html. (Because you don't need to throw out addAll and revert to an ugly manual loop for ALL devices, just those running < HONEYCOMB.)

Comment: IMO checking the build is uglier